# Copy content from one nattable to other with same object type

Tags: nattable

Copy content (multiple rows) from one nattable to other. Both the nattables have same object type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy and paste something, you need to parse the content in the clipboard. NatTable does not support this out of the box. You will need to implement some paste command handler that can take content from the clipboard to create new objects with the data available in the clipboard.

Comment: Do we have any example